# Executing a function attached to a button

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I am currently trying to execute a function that has been pre-declared.
The function is attached to a button but when i click the button i get the error message 'PopupPicker has not been declared'. 
Below is a copy of my function and the buttons that are trying to execute the function.

```
function PopupPicker(ctl,w,h)
{
    var PopupWindow = null;
    settings='width='+ w + ',height='+ h + ',location=no,directories=no, menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,dependent=no';
    PopupWindow=window.open(<%= getServerName.getserverName("/Quoteman/DatePicker.aspx?Ctl=") %> + ctl,'DatePicker',settings);
    PopupWindow.focus();
}
```

This are the buttons.

```
<td style="width: 120px">
    <asp:TextBox ID="DateOutTxt" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" ImageUrl="~/icons/vwicn063.gif" OnClientClick="PopupPicker('DateOutTxt', 250, 250);" Width="21px" />
</td>
<td colspan="2" style="width: 100%">
    <asp:TextBox ID="DateInTxt" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" ImageUrl="~/icons/vwicn063.gif" OnClientClick="PopupPicker('DateInTxt', 250, 250);" Width="21px" />
</td>
<td colspan="1" style="width: 100px">
</td>
```

The languages are javascript and html with some VB.Net in there.

Comment: try passing single param in the function say PopupPicker('DateInTxt'), does it still give that msg then?

Comment: Where do you define your JS function in the <head/> or at the end of the <body/>? Could be that you're clicking the element before the javascript function has been loaded. Also, there might be a JS error somewhere in your code that makes the whole JS chunk not available in the browser. Check your console for errors.

Comment: If I try and pass a single parameter then I would not be able to declare the size of the popup.

Comment: I have tried moving the script tags above the td tags and it doesn't work that way either. At the minute the function is below the </body> tag.

Comment: have you still tried with a single param? does it not work then too?

Comment: I still get the error message with just one parameter.

Comment: move the script tags inside head tags and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you declare the function either **inside** `<head></head>` or **inside** `<body></body>`.
Like this:

```
<html>
  <head> ... </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script>
      function PopupPicker(ctl,w,h) { ... }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should **not** put anything except comments or `</html>` below the `</body>` tag. It is not valid.

If you are using jQuery, make sure your function is not declared inside jQuery's $(document).ready() but outside of it. Like this:

```
<script>
  function PopupPicker(ctl,w,h) { ... }
  $(document).ready(function(){..})
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think it is using jquery, but i am not 100% because it is a company application.

Comment: Just asked my manager and the application doesn't use jquery.

Comment: Where is the function declared exactly?

Comment: Ah. You are declaring the function after </body>. Try moving it above </body> and it should work.